# Creating a json column within a group by in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a data set like below

```
NAME-----T----V

Adam-----90---1
Adam-----91---2
Adam-----93---3
Matt-----90---0
Matt-----91---9
Matt-----93---8
```

I want to get it like this

```
Adam, [{"90": 1}, {"91": 2}, {"93", 3}]
Matt, [{"90": 0}, {"91": 9}, {"93", 8}]
```

How should I create a script in the group by clause to get a single line with aggregated values?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/j4JvoCpE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You build an object using `json_build_object` (or `jsonb_build_object` for jsonb) and aggregate into an array using `json_agg`:

```
select name
     , json_agg(json_build_object(t, v))
  from so
 group by name
```

[Live demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/1THtGFdl)

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the exact answer for my question. However I missed a part. The T value repeats and I need the MAX(V) in my json object. Here I edited the table https://dbfiddle.uk/_jfVlmsy

Comment: Just group by name and t, select max(v) in a cte or a subquery and then do the same on the aggregated dataset.